# How to push values in array for JSON in php?

Tags: php, json

In php, I am making an array to be turned into a JSON string.

This works, if I hardcode them:

```
                $data = array(
                    'firstname' => mysql_result($recordset, 0, 'first name'),
                    'lastname' => mysql_result($recordset, 0, 'last name'),
                    'email' => mysql_result($recordset, 0, 'email address'),
                    'password' => mysql_result($recordset, 0, 'password'),
                    'phone' => mysql_result($recordset, 0, 'mobile number'),
                    'website' => mysql_result($recordset, 0, 'website link'),
                    'type' => mysql_result($recordset, 0, 'type_id'),
                    'active' => mysql_result($recordset, 0, 'active'),
                    'datejoined' => mysql_result($recordset, 0, 'date joined'),
                    'dateleft' => mysql_result($recordset, 0, 'date left'),
                    'datelastactive' => mysql_result($recordset, 0, 'date last active'),
                    'status' => mysql_result($recordset, 0, 'status'),
                    'biotext' => mysql_result($recordset, 0, 'bio text'),
                    'picURL' => $picURL
                );
```

But if I try a loop

```
            $data = array();
            for ($i = 0; $i < $num_records; $i++) {
                array_push($data, "location{$i}" => mysql_result($recordset, $i, 'location'));
            }
```

I get the error

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_DOUBLE_ARROW
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try

```
    $data = array();
    for ($i = 0; $i < $num_records; $i++) {
       $data["location{$i}"] = mysql_result($recordset, $i, 'location');
    }
```

to make it associative, and then

```
$myJSON = json_encode($data);
```

to get JSON

Answer (score 2):

You need to put array as a second argument of `array_push`. Don't use `array_push` at all. Try something like this instead

```
$data["location{$i}"] = mysql_result($recordset, $i, 'location')));
```

Comment: maybe because you answer is wrong? your example returns `Array([0]=>Array([location{0}]=>'somevalue'),[1]=>Array([location{1}]=>'anothervalue'), ...)` not `Array([location{0}]=>'somevalue',[location{1}]=>'anothervalue', ...)`

Comment: What a begginer mistake -_- Thank you.